# Store multiples off 11 in an array up to 1000 in MIPS

Tags: mips, mips64

(MIPS) I'm trying to store multiple's of 11 up to 1000 in an array and then trying to print them out in a sperate loop (I know i can do it a one loop all together)

```
.data

array11 : .space 360
.text




while :
    beq $t0, 360,exit
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $s0, $s0, 7
    sw $s0,array11 ($t0)
    
    
    j while

addi $t0, $zero, 0
exit:
loop :
    beq $t0, 360,exit
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    lw $t6, array11($t0)
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t6
    syscall
    j while
```

Comment: Don't tag spam your questions with unrelated tags; e.g. `[java]`.

Comment: Ok, so ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea for how to do two separate loops, but there are a few problems with what's in those loops. I'll go through the code, one step at a time and come to a possible solution:

```
.text

while :
    beq $t0, 360,exit
```

To start with, your program begins with the first instruction after the `.text` declaration. Therefore the first thing you do in your program is compare `$t0` to 360. The problem with that is, there's no way of knowing what value `$t0` holds. Your operating system uses registers just like your program does, and so it could contain anything. Presumably you're trying to loop from 0 to 360, so you need to set `$t0` to 0 before you start comparing it.

```
.text
move $t0,$zero
while:
    beq $t0, 360,exit
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $s0, $s0, 7
    sw $s0,array11 ($t0)
    
    
    j while
```

Now let's move on to the loop itself. The syntax you're using here `sw $s0, array11($t0)` could work, but there's no guarantee, as offset values have a limited range. It depends on what the address of `array11` happens to be - and you don't want to rely on that if you don't have to. It's better to write it like this. We'll use the register `$t2` for the loop counter

```
.text
la $t0,array11
move $t2,$zero
while:
   
   beq $t2,360,exit
   addi $t0,$t0,4  #increment pointer
   addi $t2,$t2,1  #increment loop counter
   addi $s0,$s0,7  #???
   sw $s0,0($t0)   #store in array
   j while
```

This, I'm not sure I understand. Why add 7 to `$s0` if the goal is to output multiples of 11? Here's what I'd do to fix that.

```
.text
la $t0,array11
move $t2,$zero
move $s0,$zero
while:
   beq $t2,360,exit
   addi $t0,$t0,4  #increment pointer
   addi $t2,$t2,1  #increment loop counter
   addi $s0,$s0,11 #next multiple of 11.
   sw $s0,0($t0)   #store in array
   j while
```

Now that this is working, you can reduce the number of instrutions by changing how your loop is structured.

```
.text
la $t0,array11
li $t1,360
move $t2,$zero
move $s0,$zero
while:
   addi $t0,$t0,4     #increment pointer
   addi $t2,$t2,1     #increment loop counter
   addi $s0,$s0,11    #next multiple of 11.
   sw $s0,0($t0)      #store in array
   bltu $t2,$t1,while #loop while $t2 < 360
```

This version effectively merges the `j while` and `beq $t0,360,exit` into one instruction which will make your loop faster.